# Read bookmarks in outlook MSG file with C#

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, bookmarks, msg

My goal is to somehow be able to read bookmarks in an outlook .msg file, then replace them with a different text. I want to do this with C#.

I know how to access the body and change the text, but was wondering if there was a way to access directly the list of all the bookmarks and its location so that i can easily replace them, instead going through the whole body text, splitting it up, etc etc...

edit: [this is how a bookmark window looks like](http://blogs.office.com/cfs-filesystemfile.ashx/__key/CommunityServer-Blogs-Components-WeblogFiles/00-00-00-00-45/3326.Bookmark_2D00_dialog_2D00_box.jpg) from this window one can assign bookmarks, but it should be possible to obtain this list via c#.

[image]

Any relevant info is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I feel stupid, but what do you mean by bookmarks in an e-mail?

Comment: Do you mean hyperlinks in the body of the message?

Comment: if you press ctrl+shift+F5
you will get the bookmark window, from here, you can assign bookmarks on words/text.

Answer (score 0):

Since Outlook [most often uses Word as it's body editor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868598.aspx) - you need to add a project reference to *Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll* and then access to the Outlook Inspector's [`WordEditor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868196.aspx) during the [`Inspector.Activate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.inspectorevents_10_event.activate%28v=office.14%29.aspx) event. Once you have access to the [`Word.Document`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840898.aspx) - it's trivial to [load up the `Bookmarks`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194977.aspx) and access/modify their values.

```
Outlook.Inspector inspector = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveInspector();
((Outlook.InspectorEvents_10_Event)inspector).Activate += () =>
{   // validation to ensure we are using Word Editor
    if (inspector.EditorType == Outlook.OlEditorType.olEditorWord && inspector.IsWordMail())
    {
        Word.Document wordDoc = inspector.WordEditor as Word.Document;
        if (wordDoc != null)
        {
            var bookmarks = wordDoc.Bookmarks;
            foreach (Word.Bookmark item in bookmarks)
            {
                string name = item.Name; // bookmark name
                Word.Range bookmarkRange = item.Range; // bookmark range
                string bookmarkText = bookmarkRange.Text; // bookmark text
                item.Select(); // triggers bookmark selection
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: I have referenced as you said to microsoft.office.interop.word.dll, but when i write the first line, i cant find Globals.ThisAddIn.....

Comment: What version of Visual Studio and Office are you using? [Globals.ThisAddIn is automatically generated by Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bhczd18c.aspx) for an Office plugin project. If you are not using an Outlook Plugin - you won't have Globals.ThisAddIn.

Comment: im using vs2005 and office 2007
i have also the outlook interop referenced.